# How to get all capture camera video resolutions for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, video, resolution

When I try to enumerate all formats that camera supports in my phone

```
videoCaptureDevice = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice();
foreach (var item in device.SupportedFormats)
{
    //display formats
}
```

I get only one value: 640 X 480

I don't understand and need help to get other formats (that I can see in native camera application like 320X240, 640X480, 1280X720) to apply for capturing video.

Comment: Do you run this code on device or on the emulator?

Comment: on device. On emulator I get 640X480 and I suppose it's OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a WP7 SDK limitation.
You can find the discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/a76211a9-cba2-4fee-8a7d-2fc6915f9e92/).